# some doubts in one paragraph

Tags: word-choice, tense, questions

In the following paragraph I have some doubts. The first one is in which tense is acceptable to use in this context. The other doubts are emphasized in their place. My doubts say that I'm not sure if it's correct to use in this words or styling by English native speaker (that I'm not one of them...). Here is the spoken paragraph:

Imagine that you are in the anatomy class, and the professor gives you this bone and ask you these three questions:

> **1) In which** place in the body, this bone is located?**
>
> 2) What is its name
>
> 3) **Do according to what** you can decide that it's what you answered?

Comment: The (3) is a bit unclear.  Can you rephrase somehow?  It sounds like two questions squeezed into one sentence.

Comment: Thank you, I just meant to ask  "according to what you decide about your answer". Maybe now it's clearer. (That's exactly the problem that I don't now how to express myself in English - in this case...

Comment: Do you mean in 3) "How did you decide/determine that your answer was the correct one?" I would not use "do" if you are not asking someone to do something.

Answer (score 2):

The native speaker would probably phrase those questions similarly to

> What region of the body did this bone come from?
>   What is its name?  - or -  What is it called?
>   What did you base your conclusion on?  - or -  What helped you arrive at your answer?

Of course there can be numerous variations, especially on the latter question.  Somebody with education in anatomy should probably know more of the idioms they use when discussing bones and parts of the body.  I have a very limited knowledge in that field.

Comment: But can I not using "according to what" in my question?

Comment: By the way I thought about  "Which sign did you base your conclusion on" or "What sign helped you arrive at your answer?" both of these two options are instead of "According to what etc."